# Flex 4 Mobile Alert Issue

Tags: apache-flex

Anyone knows knows why an alert with an ip address is generated in my mobile app when I build to Android. I'm calling web services and thought that could be the issue. I don't have the alert in my code anywhere. Also, I played around with the permissions for Android to see if that was the issue. The alerts just popup randomly.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the alert?  Perhaps the full text of the alert?  It is definitely unusual that you would see "Random alerts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Your handset has to be on the same network as your development computer when running in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Disable network monitor of flash builder and build the application again.